# Python. Как объявить тип элементов в пустом списке, что-бы отображались подсказки свойств этого типа в PyCharm?

Tags: python-3.x, классы, list, pycharm, ide

Столкнулся с проблемой, которая наверняка очень просто решается, но... сам не понимаю.
Среда разработки - PyCharm.
Объявляю пустой список, элементы в него будут добавляться динамически пользователем приложения. В процессе кодинга в PyCharm подсказки не появляются, так как элемента в списке еще не существует и его тип неизвестен по определению.

```
obj = list()
```

У меня есть некий класс:

```
class obj_property:
    obj_name = ''
    obj_img_path = ''
    obj_posX = 0
    obj_posY = 0
```

Каким образом можно дать знать IDE, что в списке будут элементы типа **obj_property**. Что-бы впоследствии они имели подсказки вида:

```
obj[1].obj_name
obj[i].obj_posX
```

Через генератор списка я могу обозначить тип:

```
obj = [obj_property(None) for i in range(5000)]
```

**Возможно ли сделать то же самое без использования генератора? Так как количество будущих элементов в списке неизвестно.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Последние версии питона поддерживают тайпхинты
https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html
В итоге Ваше объявление можно сделать таким

```
from typing import List
obj: List[obj_property] = []
```

Но надо понимать, что это никак не ограничивает возможность занести в этот лист какой-то другой элемент.

Так же рекомендую все таки придерживаться [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) при нейминге и переименовать класс в `ObjProperty`

Comment: А вот это работает!
https://ibb.co/kGzRcLN
Спасибо огромное)
В остальном - в моем случае в этот массив заносятся элементы одного типа (именно для них он создается), а с PEP-8 согласен, но тут дело привычки через_подчеркивание_именовать. Кроме меня в этот код никто не полезет, тем не менее PyCharm выдает предупреждения, я их вижу)

Comment: И отдельное спасибо за ссылку. Я в Python совсем недавно, думаю, по меркам программистов пол года это ниже чем новичек. Я пока использовал только базовый синтаксис вида a=5, a = MyClass() и т.п.

Comment: Андрей, можно еще вопрос? Быть может подскажете где почитать про этот синтаксис? Я пока не могу понять значение ":" и "->". В базовых учебниках и мануалах не нахожу их значения.

Comment: Рано порадовался. Подсказки заработали, но прога перестала запускаться((
Ошибка циклического импорта. Это уже мой косяк в модулях.

Comment: хм... как ни странно, подсказки работают, но зато приложение летит к чертям . С трудом нашел уже то, что поправил по предложенным хинтам. Вылетало с exit code.

Comment: @Павел https://stackoverflow.com/a/32558710/7186864 тут рассказывают о них, либо можно искать по фразам "питон аннотации типов", "python type hints"

Comment: Надо удостовериться еще, что у Вас подходящая версия питон, так как анотации типов постепенно развивались в питоне и раньше их использовали, через определение в комментариях, потом стало можно добавлять их как часть программы. Сначала для переменных, потом как параметры в методах. Я сейчас не скажу в какой версии питон, что именно вводилось

Comment: Я внес изменения, что бы использовать List из модуля typing, проверьте может Вам поможет

Comment: @Павел пробуйте имя класса как строку указать и убрать импорт этого класса: `obj: List["obj_property"] = []`

Comment: Если не разберетесь с циклическим импортом, можно вопрос задать, с указанием какие классы в каких модулях и что откуда импортируется.

Comment: Спасибо. Пока разбираюсь, я в своем коде много поменял, где-то накосячил. В данный момент не могу сказать что помогло, а что нет. Сначала восстановлю чтоб прога работала, потом отпишусь.
Про питон - у меня версия 3.9
IDE PyCharm  (много букв) обновление от 21 апреля.

Comment: @insolor разобрался, дело было не в бабине))) Тупо не сделал импорт from typing import List
Всё отлично работает.

Comment: @Andrey Maslov, разобрался, мой косяк. Не прописал импорт from typing import List
Всё работает как надо!

Answer (score 3):

Объявить кому? Другим программистам, которые будут читать код? Напишите в комментариях или type hints. Для интерпретатора все ваши объявления не имеют никакого значения, т.к. в любой список всегда можно положить все что угодно. Даже ваш генератор это не обозначение типа, как вы почему-то думаете, а просто заполнение списка объектами класса. Ничего не мешает потом любой элемент заменить числом, строкой, объектом другого класса и т.д.

Comment: Мне это нужно именно для кодинга.
Смотрите что видно с генератором, который объявляет тип элементов (даже со значением None)
https://ibb.co/7Ch4xLX
И что происходит без генератора. Просто объявление пустого списка.
https://ibb.co/xDy9H0Q

Comment: Генератор не объявляет(!) тип элементов. Он заполняет список элементами.

Comment: Всё верно, заполняет. Но при заполнении можно объявить тип элемента. Возможно, я неверно выражаю мысли и задачи. Прошу простить и понять) Я в питоне недавно. Спасибо за уделенное внимание к моему вопросу.

Answer (score 1):

Питон - язык с динамической типизацией. Кроме того, в питоновском списке могут быть вперемешку элементы любых типов. Поэтому объявлять заранее ничего не нужно, питон автоматически увидит поля класса, когда вы к ним обратитесь.

Comment: Увы, не видит. Даже в PyCharm.
https://ibb.co/DKhVQWc
В остальном - полностью согласен и понимаю, что элементы списка могут быть любого типа. Но пока тип не задан - свойства и методы не показываются, они определяются когда элемент/переменная уже существует. А это происходит во время выполнения приложения. В процессе кодинга этих элементов еще не существует.

Comment: Питон - увидит. Ваше "увы" относится подсказками в IDE, а не к языку.

Comment: @Эникейщик
Вы правы. Питон выполняет инструкции, но IDE выдает предупреждения. Да и прописывать свойства в коде приходится по своей памяти. 
Ответ, который решает мою проблему, уже дан. Видимо с моей стороны стоит откорректировать вопрос, что-бы упоминалась среда разработки.